# Problem formatting a Datetime column in a Datagridview object

Tags: c#, mariadb, date-formatting

I have a Datagridview object that I use to display information from a MariaDB SQL server. For some reason I can't properly format a Date column on it. I am trying to format the dates to European style (dd/MM/yyyy) but the program doesn't format it when I use a **DefaultCellStyle.Format** command on the column and if I format it in the SQL query it becomes impossible to sort that column, it throws an exception:

[image: link]

Here is the query I am attempting:

```
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT
        " + table + @".ID,
        teams_and_managers.Team AS team, 
        teams_and_managers.Manager AS manager,
        subprojects.ProjectName AS project,
        subprojects.Nickname AS subproject,
        products.Product AS product,
        QT, Comment,
        Date_Format(DateOpen, '%d/%m/%Y')   //The issue is with this column
        FROM " + table + @"
        INNER JOIN inventory_commander.teams_and_managers ON  " + table + @".Team = teams_and_managers.ID
        INNER JOIN inventory_commander.subprojects ON  " + table + @".Project = subprojects.id 
        INNER JOIN " + database + @".products ON  " + table + @".Product = products.ID           
        AND Status=0 AND teams_and_managers.Team LIKE @team AND subprojects.ProjectName LIKE @project and subprojects.Nickname LIKE @subproject AND (products.Product LIKE @search OR Comment LIKE @search) AND (DateOpen BETWEEN @datestart AND @dateend)
        ORDER BY DateOpen DESC";
```

The **table** and **database** variables are used to switch between test and prod environments.

How can I properly format the date value here so it can be sorted?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried adding an alias to the DateOpen column:

```
Date_Format(DateOpen, '%d/%m/%Y') AS DateOpen
```

the column can now be sorted but it seems like its now treating the column like its a string e.g. it sorts based on the first-second-third value:

```
25/07/2019
25/07/2019
25/07/2019
12/09/2019
12/09/2019
12/09/2019
12/09/2019
12/09/2019
12/09/2019
04/12/2019
04/12/2019
04/12/2019
03/09/2019
03/09/2019
02/09/2019
```

Comment: What happens if you alias that column (`AS DateOpen`, for instance) and use that alias in the cell style format?

Comment: Don't format it in the SQL. Allow it to come back as a `Date` and use the cell style to format it for display.

Comment: Already tried that, left it as Date and used DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy" to try and format it but its it just completely ignores the command.